# Can Iron Dragon Charge be used each time, or only once?

Tags: dnd-4e, powers

Iron Dragon Charge (PHB I) reads:

> Until the end of the encounter, as an immediate
>   reaction, an ally of your choice within 5 squares of you can
>   charge a target that you charge.

Does this imply that it works once until it is used up or the encounter ends - or each time the warlord charges?

Comment: It is worded incredibly ambiguously. I came up with over five different interpretations almost immediately (does it have to be the same enemy who was the target of the attack, do you choose the ally each time you charge or is it always the same one, etc.) after reading it and my interest has now been piqued as well. I will do extensive research on the topic, but there is a chance that, as the rules updates part of the old D&D site was taken down along with the rest of it, it will be significantly difficult to come across the official answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Checking against other abilities that use the same wording (and the errata), it is exactly as it reads: While in this stance each time you charge a companion can join you in that charge against that foe.

However: note that it is a Stance, so if you change stances this ends.

As a note: how many times will you realistically charge in an encounter? And this is (IIRC) a daily. So it's far less powerful than it looks.

Comment: Yeah.  This is basically how stances work in 4th.  It 's possible to make it pretty powerful, but it requires building multiple members of the party around it to do so (and controlling the battlefield), and that kind of party optimization (and battlefield control) can get you significant amounts of power in a lot of places in 4th ed.

Comment: Side note: Charging actually is/was a popular tactic for maximizing DPR in the character optimization circles, due to numerous options for getting extra damage on a charge.

Answer (score 1):

The implication (intended or otherwise) is that it can be used repeatedly until the end of the encounter.

Short of an errata rewrite, that would be my official DM ruling.